# iOS 6 Accounts framework error: Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol

Tags: ios, xcode

I got this strange error in my XCode 4.6.2 project. Any one had the same problem before.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/7rgpoh8m6akr0c9/accounts_framework_error.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the include right before the @class statement, AccountDefines.

Comment: I can't edit the file because it's in a framework (Accounts framework),
Plus I have the same file in another project and there is no errors

Comment: Something has to be wrong or you wouldn't get those errors. Try using Product:Generate Output:Preprocess on the .m file, maybe you can see what it thinks is wrong with the expanded source file. Do you define anything in your .pch file? Something is causing the compiler to compile something incorrect at that point. Generally it will complain about undefined classes if they were never compiled successfully earlier in the source file. With preprocess you might see where a #define of yours messed up something in AcountsDefines.

Comment: Shame on me :(
It turned out to be a stupid typo in main.m file which cost me a whole day of painful and desperate work,
Thanks for trying to help @ahwulf

Comment: Typo'd myself to death more than once :-)

Comment: because @MongiZaidi 's comment helped me find my own error  - I wanted to share if someone might be in a similar situation: In Debug Mode with Breakpoints enabled I ran into an error and the app stopped at the main.m file with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.. before running it again i pressed Cmd+Shift+k and accidentally pressed "<k" thus leading to these characters being inserted at the beginning of main.m and leading to that strange typo error..

Answer (score -1):

> in my code this  is syntax error . Add semi-colon after UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR tag. Prevent Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol error.