# Resolving Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

first, I tried all of the other solution provided in similar question on this site. but no luck.

Here is the file `FMResultSet.h` which gives error

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

#ifndef __has_feature      // Optional.
#define __has_feature(x) 0 // Compatibility with non-clang compilers.
#endif

#ifndef NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED
#if __has_feature(attribute_ns_returns_not_retained)
#define NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED __attribute__((ns_returns_not_retained))
#else
#define NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED
#endif
#endif

@class FMDatabase;      // <-- here it gives error (Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol)
@class FMStatement;

@interface FMResultSet : NSObject {
    FMDatabase          *_parentDB;
    FMStatement         *_statement;

    NSString            *_query;
    NSMutableDictionary *_columnNameToIndexMap;
    BOOL                _columnNamesSetup;
}

@property (atomic, retain) NSString *query;
@property (atomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *columnNameToIndexMap;
@property (atomic, retain) FMStatement *statement;

+ (id)resultSetWithStatement:(FMStatement *)statement usingParentDatabase:(FMDatabase*)aDB;

- (void)close;

- (void)setParentDB:(FMDatabase *)newDb;

- (BOOL)next;
- (BOOL)hasAnotherRow;

- (int)columnCount;

- (int)columnIndexForName:(NSString*)columnName;
- (NSString*)columnNameForIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (int)intForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (int)intForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (long)longForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (long)longForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (long long int)longLongIntForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (long long int)longLongIntForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (unsigned long long int)unsignedLongLongIntForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (unsigned long long int)unsignedLongLongIntForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (BOOL)boolForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (BOOL)boolForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (double)doubleForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (double)doubleForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (NSString*)stringForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (NSString*)stringForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (NSDate*)dateForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (NSDate*)dateForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (NSData*)dataForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
- (NSData*)dataForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (const unsigned char *)UTF8StringForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;
- (const unsigned char *)UTF8StringForColumnName:(NSString*)columnName;

// returns one of NSNumber, NSString, NSData, or NSNull
- (id)objectForColumnName:(NSString*)columnName;
- (id)objectForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx;

- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)columnName;
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(int)columnIdx;

/*
If you are going to use this data after you iterate over the next row, or after you close the
result set, make sure to make a copy of the data first (or just use dataForColumn:/dataForColumnIndex:)
If you don't, you're going to be in a world of hurt when you try and use the data.
*/
- (NSData*)dataNoCopyForColumn:(NSString*)columnName NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;
- (NSData*)dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:(int)columnIdx NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;

- (BOOL)columnIndexIsNull:(int)columnIdx;
- (BOOL)columnIsNull:(NSString*)columnName;


/* Returns a dictionary of the row results mapped to case sensitive keys of the column names. */
- (NSDictionary*)resultDictionary;

/* Please use resultDictionary instead.  Also, beware that resultDictionary is case sensitive! */
- (NSDictionary*)resultDict  __attribute__ ((deprecated));

- (void)kvcMagic:(id)object;


@end
```

Comment: And how are you using the file? What is it being included into?

Comment: `@class FMDatabase;` what you got in this line? give more explanation..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @class, do #import "FMDatabase.h"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether are you using any protocols in "FMDatabase.h".

if you implemented any protocol in your file, then that protocol make you problem. try to use that correctly in your "FMResultSet.h"

I hope protocol implementation may be your problem.

Other possibility

Please check this link [iOS 6 Accounts framework error: Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690172/ios-6-accounts-framework-error-prefix-attribute-must-be-followed-by-an-interfac)

This link may also help you.